# JAXB/Moxy @XmlPath(".") conflicts with the XMLAdapter during the unmarshalling

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling, moxy

Was unable to find the solution even after trying many things so posting here hoping to get some workaround or fix for this issue.

Basically, if the `@XmlPath(".")` has been used on a `Map` and if there is `XMLAdapter` on it then it fails during the `unmarshalling`. The `marshaling` works perfectly only the `unmarshalling` fails.

In short, I would like to perform the `unmarshalling` [as mentioned here](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html) but along with `Map` I will have one more `@XmlElement`. So one field is annotated with `(Map field) @XmlPath(".")` and another String field with `@XmlElement` and then I would like to perform `unmarshalling`.

Following is the `XML` that I am trying to `unmarshal`:

```
<Customer xmlns:google="https://google.com">
  <name>Batman</name>
  <age>2008</age>
  <google:sub1>MyValue-1</google:sub1>
  <google:sub2>MyValue-1</google:sub2>
</Customer>
```

Following is the `Customer.class` to which it will be `unmarshalled`:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Customer")
@XmlType(name = "Customer", propOrder = {"name", "age", "userExtensions"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Customer extends Person {

  private String name;
  private String age;

  @XmlPath(".")
  @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(TestAdapter.class)
  @XmlAnyElement
  private Map<String, Object> userExtensions = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Following is the `Main` class which will `unmarshal`:

```
public class Unmarshalling {
  public static void main(String[] args)
      throws JAXBException, XMLStreamException, FactoryConfigurationError, IOException, URISyntaxException, ProcessingException {
    final InputStream inputStream = Unmarshalling.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("customer.xml");
    final XMLStreamReader xmlStreamReader = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(inputStream);
    final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Customer.class);
    final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
    final Customer customer = unmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStreamReader, Customer.class).getValue();
    System.out.println("Read XML : " + customer);
  }
}
```

When I run this code I will get the output as:

```
Read XML : Person(name=Rise Against, age=2000)
```

Its not reading the `custom` elements such as `google:sub1` and `google:sub2`.

1. There is one more [issue similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27765087/7584240) but the workaround mentioned there did not work for me.
2. I tried the `@XmlAnyElement(lax=true)` on `MAP` even that did not work for me.

Following is the `TestAdapter` that I am using for `marshalling` and `unmarhsalling` the `Map<String,Object>`

```
public class TestAdapter extends XmlAdapter<Wrapper, Map<String, Object>> {

  @Override
  public Map<String, Object> unmarshal(Wrapper value) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("ADAPTER UNMARSHALLING");
    System.out.println(value.getElements());

    if (value == null) {
      return null;
    }

    //Loop across all elements within ILMD tag
    final Map<String, Object> extensions = new HashMap<>();
    for (Object obj : value.getElements()) {
      Element element = (Element) obj;

      //System.out.println("Node Name : " + element.getNodeName() + " Value : " + element.getTextContent());

      final NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();

      if (children.getLength() == 1) {
        extensions.put(element.getNodeName(), element.getTextContent());
      } else {
        List<Object> child = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) {
          final Node n = children.item(i);
          if (n.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
            List childElements = new ArrayList();
            childElements.add(n);
            wrapper.elements = childElements;
            child.add(unmarshal(wrapper));
          }
        }
        extensions.put(element.getNodeName(), child);
      }
    }
    return extensions;
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  @Override
  public Wrapper marshal(Map<String, Object> v) throws Exception {
    if (v == null) {
      return null;
    }

    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
    List elements = new ArrayList();
    for (Map.Entry<String, Object> property : v.entrySet()) {
      if (property.getValue() instanceof Map) {
        elements.add(new JAXBElement<Wrapper>(new QName(property.getKey()), Wrapper.class, marshal((Map) property.getValue())));
      } else {
        elements.add(new JAXBElement<String>(new QName(property.getKey()), String.class, property.getValue().toString()));
      }
    }
    wrapper.elements = elements;
    return wrapper;
  }
}

class Wrapper {

  @XmlAnyElement
  List elements;

  public List getElements() {
    return elements;
  }
```

I tried many things but nothing worked till now. Can someone please have a look at this issue and provide your solution. Happy to provide any more info with regards to this issue as I have spent nearly 10 days looking for answers.

I tried following things:

1. Created one more variable and tried to use it only during unmarshalling but that's also failing.
2. Tried to create one more field then used the `@XmlAnyElement` on it but that's also not working as I expected.

Tried few more things but nothing helped.

Everything is failing. I tried to debug the code from `MOXY` but I am unable to follow many things there. Any help with this issue would be really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it by using the `BeforeMarshal` and `AfterMarshal` methods. Posting here so it can be helpful to someone in the future:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, visible = true, property = "isA")
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@XmlRootElement(name = "extension")
@XmlType(name = "extension", propOrder = {"name", "age", "otherElements"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Customer {
    @XmlTransient
    private String isA;

    @XmlPath("customer/name/text()")
    private String name;

    @XmlPath("customer/age/text()")
    private String age;

    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlPath("customer")
    private List<Object> otherElements = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @XmlTransient
    private Map<String, Object> userExtensions = new HashMap<>();

    @JsonAnyGetter
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomExtensionsSerializer.class)
    public Map<String, Object> getUserExtensions() {
        return userExtensions;
    }

    @JsonAnySetter
    public void setUserExtensions(String key, Object value) {
        userExtensions.put(key, value);
    }

    private void beforeMarshal(Marshaller m) throws ParserConfigurationException {
        System.out.println("Before Marshalling User Extension: " + userExtensions);
        ExtensionsModifier extensionsModifier = new ExtensionsModifier();
        otherElements = extensionsModifier.Marshalling(userExtensions);
        System.out.println("Before Marshalling Final Other Elements " + otherElements);
        userExtensions = new HashMap<>();
    }

    private void afterUnmarshal(Unmarshaller m, Object parent) throws ParserConfigurationException {
        System.out.println("After Unmarshalling : " + otherElements);
        ExtensionsModifier extensionsModifier = new ExtensionsModifier();
        userExtensions = extensionsModifier.Unmarshalling(otherElements);
        System.out.println("Final User Extensions : " + userExtensions);
        otherElements = new ArrayList();
    }
}
```

The complete answer can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67923216/7584240